# Polar Plot: Color Difficulties

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have an issue with coloring a polar plot. My data is very small except for one entry. When I plot it, it seems that all entries are at the same level, which is false.

**Setting and Data:**

Basically, what I am given is two angles (p and n) which define the position, and a power, which defines the intensity at this position.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

angle_n = np.array([-81.545 , -68.838 , -63.755 , -62.215 , -63.755 , -68.838 ,
       -81.545 , -70.76  , -59.292 , -52.565 , -48.751 , -47.498 ,
       -48.751 , -52.565 , -59.292 , -70.76  , -70.76  , -56.523 ,
       -47.498 , -41.256 , -37.442 , -36.143 , -37.442 , -41.256 ,
       -47.498 , -56.523 , -70.76  , -81.545 , -59.292 , -47.498 ,
       -38.725 , -32.116 , -27.793 , -26.254 , -27.793 , -32.116 ,
       -38.725 , -47.498 , -59.292 , -81.545 , -68.838 , -52.565 ,
       -41.256 , -32.116 , -24.649 , -19.251 , -17.152 , -19.251 ,
       -24.649 , -32.116 , -41.256 , -52.565 , -68.838 , -63.755 ,
       -48.751 , -37.442 , -27.793 , -19.251 , -12.036 ,  -8.4792,
       -12.036 , -19.251 , -27.793 , -37.442 , -48.751 , -63.755 ,
       -62.215 , -47.498 , -36.143 , -26.254 , -17.152 ,  -8.4792,
         0.    ,   8.4792,  17.152 ,  26.254 ,  36.143 ,  47.498 ,
        62.215 ,  63.755 ,  48.751 ,  37.442 ,  27.793 ,  19.251 ,
        12.036 ,   8.4792,  12.036 ,  19.251 ,  27.793 ,  37.442 ,
        48.751 ,  63.755 ,  68.838 ,  52.565 ,  41.256 ,  32.116 ,
        24.649 ,  19.251 ,  17.152 ,  19.251 ,  24.649 ,  32.116 ,
        41.256 ,  52.565 ,  68.838 ,  81.545 ,  59.292 ,  47.498 ,
        38.725 ,  32.116 ,  27.793 ,  26.254 ,  27.793 ,  32.116 ,
        38.725 ,  47.498 ,  59.292 ,  81.545 ,  70.76  ,  56.523 ,
        47.498 ,  41.256 ,  37.442 ,  36.143 ,  37.442 ,  41.256 ,
        47.498 ,  56.523 ,  70.76  ,  70.76  ,  59.292 ,  52.565 ,
        48.751 ,  47.498 ,  48.751 ,  52.565 ,  59.292 ,  70.76  ,
        81.545 ,  68.838 ,  63.755 ,  62.215 ,  63.755 ,  68.838 ,  81.545 ])

angle_p = np.array([ 26.565 ,  18.435 ,   9.4623,   0.    ,  -9.4623, -18.435 ,
       -26.565 ,  38.66  ,  30.964 ,  21.801 ,  11.31  ,   0.    ,
       -11.31  , -21.801 , -30.964 , -38.66  ,  51.34  ,  45.    ,
        36.87  ,  26.565 ,  14.036 ,   0.    , -14.036 , -26.565 ,
       -36.87  , -45.    , -51.34  ,  63.435 ,  59.036 ,  53.13  ,
        45.    ,  33.69  ,  18.435 ,   0.    , -18.435 , -33.69  ,
       -45.    , -53.13  , -59.036 , -63.435 ,  71.565 ,  68.199 ,
        63.435 ,  56.31  ,  45.    ,  26.565 ,   0.    , -26.565 ,
       -45.    , -56.31  , -63.435 , -68.199 , -71.565 ,  80.538 ,
        78.69  ,  75.964 ,  71.565 ,  63.435 ,  45.    ,   0.    ,
       -45.    , -63.435 , -71.565 , -75.964 , -78.69  , -80.538 ,
        90.    ,  90.    ,  90.    ,  90.    ,  90.    ,  90.    ,
         0.    ,  90.    ,  90.    ,  90.    ,  90.    ,  90.    ,
        90.    , -80.538 , -78.69  , -75.964 , -71.565 , -63.435 ,
       -45.    ,   0.    ,  45.    ,  63.435 ,  71.565 ,  75.964 ,
        78.69  ,  80.538 , -71.565 , -68.199 , -63.435 , -56.31  ,
       -45.    , -26.565 ,   0.    ,  26.565 ,  45.    ,  56.31  ,
        63.435 ,  68.199 ,  71.565 , -63.435 , -59.036 , -53.13  ,
       -45.    , -33.69  , -18.435 ,   0.    ,  18.435 ,  33.69  ,
        45.    ,  53.13  ,  59.036 ,  63.435 , -51.34  , -45.    ,
       -36.87  , -26.565 , -14.036 ,   0.    ,  14.036 ,  26.565 ,
        36.87  ,  45.    ,  51.34  , -38.66  , -30.964 , -21.801 ,
       -11.31  ,   0.    ,  11.31  ,  21.801 ,  30.964 ,  38.66  ,
       -26.565 , -18.435 ,  -9.4623,   0.    ,   9.4623,  18.435 ,  26.565 ])


power = np.array([  9.73210000e-05,   8.18640000e-05,   5.30620000e-06,
         1.55550000e-06,   5.40130000e-06,   8.23160000e-05,
         9.72570000e-05,   2.53220000e-04,   1.12790000e-05,
         1.91370000e-04,   1.20200000e-04,   4.27250000e-05,
         1.20510000e-04,   1.91150000e-04,   1.09320000e-05,
         2.52660000e-04,   4.06920000e-04,   1.81860000e-04,
         3.05000000e-04,   1.02440000e-04,   2.71140000e-04,
         2.15500000e-04,   2.70140000e-04,   1.01420000e-04,
         3.05370000e-04,   1.81650000e-04,   4.07740000e-04,
         2.44690000e-04,   1.13910000e-05,   3.85200000e-04,
         5.60350000e-04,   1.88400000e-04,   2.60410000e-04,
         4.21440000e-04,   2.58770000e-04,   1.89750000e-04,
         5.59970000e-04,   3.86120000e-04,   1.13540000e-05,
         2.45440000e-04,   3.28930000e-04,   6.07100000e-04,
         1.96180000e-04,   2.65270000e-04,   1.31040000e-03,
         2.74310000e-05,   4.56410000e-04,   2.81450000e-05,
         1.30970000e-03,   2.66240000e-04,   1.95680000e-04,
         6.07600000e-04,   3.30050000e-04,   1.30440000e-04,
         6.27760000e-04,   1.03400000e-03,   5.85340000e-04,
         1.24640000e-04,   2.20030000e-03,   2.40090000e-04,
         2.19610000e-03,   1.24960000e-04,   5.85290000e-04,
         1.03500000e-03,   6.28160000e-04,   1.30400000e-04,
         3.10650000e-05,   5.00850000e-04,   1.20480000e-03,
         1.25920000e-03,   5.91980000e-04,   8.12190000e-04,
         3.46180000e-01,   8.09610000e-04,   5.93080000e-04,
         1.26120000e-03,   1.20530000e-03,   5.00900000e-04,
         3.09280000e-05,   1.30600000e-04,   6.27910000e-04,
         1.03490000e-03,   5.86360000e-04,   1.23470000e-04,
         2.20150000e-03,   2.34910000e-04,   2.19730000e-03,
         1.23840000e-04,   5.86220000e-04,   1.03590000e-03,
         6.28410000e-04,   1.30560000e-04,   3.28900000e-04,
         6.08450000e-04,   1.97390000e-04,   2.63930000e-04,
         1.31250000e-03,   2.68700000e-05,   4.56070000e-04,
         2.75190000e-05,   1.31180000e-03,   2.64930000e-04,
         1.96870000e-04,   6.09000000e-04,   3.30110000e-04,
         2.45120000e-04,   1.16840000e-05,   3.84190000e-04,
         5.61060000e-04,   1.87310000e-04,   2.60190000e-04,
         4.21280000e-04,   2.58520000e-04,   1.88640000e-04,
         5.60700000e-04,   3.85130000e-04,   1.16340000e-05,
         2.45890000e-04,   4.06060000e-04,   1.82190000e-04,
         3.04070000e-04,   1.02880000e-04,   2.71300000e-04,
         2.14400000e-04,   2.70250000e-04,   1.01810000e-04,
         3.04460000e-04,   1.81940000e-04,   4.06900000e-04,
         2.53170000e-04,   1.15530000e-05,   1.91840000e-04,
         1.19750000e-04,   4.27450000e-05,   1.20010000e-04,
         1.91580000e-04,   1.11720000e-05,   2.52690000e-04,
         9.76480000e-05,   8.18080000e-05,   5.32040000e-06,
         1.49980000e-06,   5.39620000e-06,   8.22070000e-05,
         9.75410000e-05])
```

**What I would like to achieve:**

I would like to plot a polar plot where each circle of the plot defines angle_n and each position on a circle defines angle_p. The power should be visualized by the color.

This is an example plot:

[image]

**This is what I have tried so far:**

```
r = angle_n
theta = angle_p
colors = np.divide(power,10**(-4))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
c = ax.scatter(theta, r, c=colors, cmap='hsv', alpha=0.75)
fig.colorbar(c)
```

[image]

As you can see, I have not been able to in-cooperate the color for the power correctly (it's way off), and I am also not completed sure if my way of defining the plot (i.e. angle_n, angle_p) is okay.

**The source of the problem**
The power values are all very low expect for one point:

```
plt.plot(power)
```

[image]

Comment: If i understood your question right, there are 2 ways to do this, 1. Convert your power data to log range (or other custom range that makes outliers close) then plot, 2. Use custom coloring (not using devide) and manually exclude the outlier powers (using max or ...) Then add a custom color to the excluded power data (inside color array)

Comment: @a-sam Thanks for your comment ! 1. np.log(power) should do it, right ? 2. I have no experience with custom coloring. Could you provide an example of how to do it or point me to some resources, please ?